# Recursive Call to Clear Linked List?

Tags: c, list, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I'm looking for a solution to clear a linked list, and this is what I am given.

I'm not sure as how I can complete this:

```
void clearRecursively(LIST **presentNode, LIST **endNode){

       if (*presentNode == NULL)
           return;

       LIST *nextNode;

       clearRecursively(&nextNode, endNode);

      *presentNode = NULL;
      *endNode = NULL;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Linked lists are linear structures which are not well suited for recursive algorithms. Don't use a hammer if your problem is a screw.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite a linked list is a recursive structure...

Comment: @user633183: Not really. A pointer is not the objet it points to. All it is related to recursion is you can use it to implement a stack, but that's a different thing. Just out of curiosity: a ring-list would be infinite recursion then?

Comment: Is your job to make this obviously broken code work? I suggest you find some simple, working linked list code first, and use that to learn how they're supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer which points to nothing: `clearRecursively(&nextNode, endNode);`

Apart from this assigning pointers to `NULL` will not delete the memory which is being pointed by them - `free(POINTER_NAME)` is for that.

By clear I think you mean delete - since complete code hasn't been provided, here is a way (for example purpose) to do it with assumption that it is a singly linked list:

```
 //THIS TRAVERSES DOWN THE LINKED-LIST AND THEN DELETES THAT LAST NODE
 //RECURSIVELY IT DELETES THE ENTIRE LIST

 void clear_recursively(LIST **head)
 {
      if(*head!=NULL)
      {
           clear_recursively(&((*head)->next));
           free(*head);
           *head=NULL;
      }
 }
```

You just need to pass the address of the `head` pointer (pointer to the first node) and it will be finished.

If by clear you mean just to **set** the data field of the entire linked list to some **value** then:

```
 void clear_recursively(LIST *head)
 {
      if(head!=NULL)
      {
           clear_recursively(head->next);
           head->data = //SOME VALUE;
      }
 }
```